# Updating Path instead of overwrite cmd

Tags: windows-7, cmd

I am running the following cmd to set my system environment variable.

```
call C:\Windows\system32>reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
\Session Manager\Environment" /v JAVA_HOME /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\Program Files\Java
\jdk1.6.0_37"
```

I want to do something similar with my path, but I dont want to overwrite the values that are there, I just want to add to them. Will running the above command overwrite or update? If it overwrites how would I get it to update instead?

Comment: Surely you could just change the `Path` in advanced system settings? I may be missing the point though.

Comment: That is simple for 1 computer, but I am setting up multiple variables on multiple machines. Just trying to save myself some time by writing a batch script that does it.

Comment: If those machines are members of a domain, [Group Policy Preferences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772047.aspx) would arguably be the best way to handle this.

Comment: Correct but I dont want to update the other 300 computers that I dont need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `REG ADD` will overwrite the existing value, but I wrote a script that should help you.

Please pay attention to the characters after `delims=`: these aren't spaces, it's a single tab character (ASCII #9).

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Declare all variables as local.
SETLOCAL

SET GET_PATH=REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path
SET SET_PATH=REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d

REM Get %PATH% from registry and filter REG output (drop all but actual %PATH% value).
FOR /F "tokens=3* delims=   " %%P IN ('%GET_PATH% ^| FINDSTR Path') DO SET RESULT=%%P

REM Check for the trailing semicolon.
IF "%RESULT:~-1%" == ";" (SET SEMICOLON=) ELSE (SET SEMICOLON=;)

REM Add new directories to %PATH%. 
SET DIRS=C:\Foo\Bar;E:\Bar\Baz
SET RESULT=%RESULT%%SEMICOLON%%DIRS%

REM Save result to the registry.
%SET_PATH% "%RESULT%"
```